# Xamarin Froms : Label text and Image not updating on UI on click of an Label inside a viewcell of a Listview

Tags: listview, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I want to change the label text and image on a click of a bale and image which is in the viewcell of an listview . I am  using the command for the click event and implemented this in my ViewModelClass which extends the InotifyPropertyChange. On click of an image or label my view is not updating .Please help.

public class BookPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, 
    {
        #region fields
        private ObservableCollection feeds = new ObservableCollection();

```
    public ObservableCollection<FeedsModel> Feeds {
        get
        {
            return feeds; 
        }
        set {
          if(value != feeds)
            {
                feeds = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Feeds");
           }
        }
    }

    private ICommand onLikePostClicked;
    public ICommand OnLikePostClicked
    {
        get { return onLikePostClicked; }
    }

    public DayBookPageViewModel(Page page, SfListView sfListView)
    {

        GetAllFeeds(Settings.UserIdSettings);
        this.page = page;
        this.sfListView = sfListView;
        #region Commands execution 

        onLikePostClicked = new Command((e) =>
        {
            var item = (e as FeedsModel);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Love))
            {
                bool like_status = false;
                string[] strarray = item.Love.Split(',');
                for (int i = 0; i < strarray.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (strarray[i] == Settings.UserIdSettings)
                    {
                        like_status = true;

                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        like_status = false;
                    }

                }

                if(like_status)
                {
                    // unlike 
                if (!NetworkConnectionClass.GetInstance().IsConnectedToInternet())
                    ShowAlerts.GetInstance().ACRLibAlert(Strings.InternetAlert, Strings.Ok);
                else
                {

                        if (item != null)
                        {
                            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(delegate
                            {


                                item.LikeImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("like_hover");
                                item.LikeLabelColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["defaultLabels_color"];
                                OnPropertyChanged("Feeds");
                            });
                            DislikeApi dislikePostApi = new DislikeApi(this, this);
                            dislikePostApi.DisLikePost(Settings.UserIdSettings, item.postId.ToString());
                        }
                }    
                }
                else
                {
                    // like 
                if (!NetworkConnectionClass.GetInstance().IsConnectedToInternet())
                    ShowAlerts.GetInstance().ACRLibAlert(Strings.InternetAlert, Strings.Ok);
                else
                {
                        if (item != null)
                        {

                            //Todo;
                            //********* UI not updating : need to fixed ***********
                            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(delegate
                            {

                                item.LikeImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("like");
                                item.LikeLabelColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["appThemeColor"];
                                OnPropertyChanged("Feeds");


                            });
                            LikePostApi likePostApi = new LikePostApi(this, this);
                            likePostApi.LikePost(Settings.UserIdSettings, item.postId.ToString());
                        }
                }   
                }

            }
            else

            {
                if (!NetworkConnectionClass.GetInstance().IsConnectedToInternet())
                    ShowAlerts.GetInstance().ACRLibAlert(Strings.InternetAlert, Strings.Ok);
                else
                {
                    if (item != null)
                    {

                        //Todo;
                        //********* UI not updating : need to fixed ***********


                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( delegate
                        {    if (!item.Love.Contains(Settings.UserIdSettings))
                            {

                            likeimageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("like");
                            item.LikeImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("like");
                            item.LikeLabelColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["appThemeColor"];
                            OnPropertyChanged("Feeds");


                        });


      #endregion
    }
```

}

```
//  This is inside the viewcell of a listview        
        <Label x:Name="likeLabel" TextColor="{Binding LikeLabelColor, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="Like " LineBreakMode="CharacterWrap"  FontSize="12" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
        <Label.Margin>
             <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
  <On Platform="iOS" Value="0,15.5,0,0" />
  <On Platform="Android" Value="0,14,0,0" />
</OnPlatform>   
            </Label.Margin>


            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer   Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.OnLikePostClicked, Source={x:Reference customListView}}" CommandParameter ="{Binding .}"  NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your `FeedModel` object. That is where the changes happen, so you want to notify the UI whenever happens something in there.

If you want to save yourself a lot of boilerplate code, have a look at [PropertyChanged.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) which generates the `INotifyPropertyChanged` code for you at compile-time.

Comment: Hi !  Thanks for your quick reply . I have already implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged  on  my ViewModel class so why i have to  implement it on my model class also ?

Comment: Because of the reason I mentioned: you are changing a value in your model, not in your view model. It's a bit hard to explain, but you are changing a value in a field of your model. If you want that change to show up in your UI, implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your model. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I got your point what you are saying and its solves my problem. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @SeasiaCreativeCrew Great! Please don’t forget to accept as an answer!